Blocked mixed content, HTTP request
please help me - I need to send requests to an API that runs on an insecure HTTP protocol. Unfortunately, I can't use PHP, but I have to use AJAX (the API server runs on localhost), so only a device connected to the same network can access it. However, the browser reports blocked mixed content.
I found something about CSR, but I can't set it up at all.
This is the connection of the payment terminal to the e-shop. Script runs from the e-shop administration and employee should be able to control it on the same network from a PC, or even a mobile phone without settings the browser.
Could you please advise me how to ideally solve this? Thank you very much for your help. :)

Share the exact errors you're getting, where you are seeing these errors and examples of URLs that you're using that are causing this (both the url in the browser and the url you're trying to hit).
